# DB2 string concatenation of longer varchars with space literal fails

Tags: db2

I've stumbled across a weird problem with varchar concatenation and the trim function. I'm using DB2 11.1.1.2.

My table consists of short and long varchars:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id integer,
name_short varchar(200),
name2_short varchar(200),
name_long varchar(2000),
name2_long varchar(2000)
)
```

**What works:**

If I concatenate two (shorter) `varchars` and pass them to the `TRIM` functions, it works just fine:

```
SELECT trim( name_short ||  name2_short ) from test;
```

Adding a space between is also no problem:

```
SELECT trim( name_short || ' ' ||  name2_short ) from test;
```

Concatenating the two longer varchars works, too:

```
SELECT trim( name_long || name2_long ) from test;
```

**What doesn't work**: Adding the space now fails!

```
SELECT trim( name_long || ' ' || name2_long ) from test;
```

Result:

> The statement was not processed because the data type, length or value of the argument for the parameter in position "string-expr" of routine "SYSIBM.TRIM" is incorrect. Parameter name: "".. SQLCODE=-171, SQLSTATE=42815, DRIVER=4.16.53

Why does this fail - and how could it be fixed?

- Trim expects a varchar as the expression  to trim
- According to the [db2 docs for the concatenation operator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000736.html), the result of concatenating two varchars should be:

  - For z/OS: a varchar with length equal to the sum of the operands length (or 32764 if smaller).
  - For LUW edition (Linux Unix Windows): a Longvarchar **Edit: Linux version added**

**Alternatives I've tried**

- Casting the string literal: `SELECT trim( name_long || cast( ' ' as varchar) || name2_long ) from test;` (same error)
- Casting the whole expression to varchar before passing it to trim
- Note: Changing one of the longer columns to a length of 2001 will fail the third example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -171 sqlcode is happening because Db2-LUW may be converting `name_long || ' ' || name2_long` into a datatype LONG VARCHAR, which TRIM dislikes.
You may get a different outcome if you explicitly cast like this:

`SELECT trim( varchar(name_long || ' ' || name2_long) ) from test;`

You can also check what Db2 is doing via:
`describe select name_long || ' '||name2_long from test;`

I tried  on Db2-LUW v11.1.3.3 , and casting to VARCHAR yields a correct result.

So you might want to apply the latest fixpack and retry.

Answer (score 1):

As mao indicates, a `CONCAT` of columns whose "Combined Length Attributes" is greater than 4000 returns a `LONG VARCHAR`. See table 1 on this page https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000736.html
so you will need to explicitly cast the type to `VARCHAR`.

Interestingly, on Db2 Warehouse in NPS compat mode does not need the cast.

```
set sql_compat='NPS';
SELECT trim( name_long || ' ' || name2_long ) from test;
```

Answer (score 0):

CHR(32) works fine, like this example.

```
 select trim(authid)||chr(32)||trim(authidtype)from sysibmadm.authorizationids
```

Output.

```
PUBLIC G
SYSROLE_AUTH_DBADM R
SYSROLE_AUTH_EXPLAIN R
```